# Scroll function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a certain class to the header if the scroller is at a certain position.

here is my code:

```
var headerHeight = $('header').height();
if($(window).scrollTop()==headerHeight) {
   $('header').addClass('scroll');
}
```

I'm getting the header's height cause i have a paragraph that can be closed, and I want when the scroller goes pass this value to add the class

The question is why is my function not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're just testing scroll position once rather than checking it whenever the window is scrolled. What you need to do is to attach a function to the `scroll` event itself, so that whenever the document is scrolled your code will execute.  Like this:

```
var headerHeight = $('header').height();
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.scrollTop() >= headerHeight) {
         $('header').addClass('scroll');
    }
});
```

If you want to remove `.scroll` from the `<header>` when the user scrolls back above its height, then you can add the following `else` clause to the `if` above:

```
else {
     $('header').removeClass('scroll');
}
```